# How can I have a upload auto linked in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, upload, charts

I have a form that uploads a file with other information to a database and displays it in a chart. Right now the chart only displays the file name and doesen't link it. If the file was called test1.pdf, how would I make it so on the chart it still says chart1.pdf but links it to the directory that the file is on?

```
                       if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxxx");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("jjlliinn_test", $con);


$target = "clientdoc/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

$date = $_POST['date'];
$propertydescription = $_POST['propertydescription'];
$transactiontype = $_POST['transactiontype'];
$applicabledocument = ($_FILES['file']['name']); 
$received = $_POST['received'];
$paid = $_POST['paid'];

//Writes the to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo ""; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transactions` (`date`, `agentclient`, `propertydescription`, `transactiontype`, `applicabledocument`, `received`, `paid`) 
VALUES
 ('$date', '$agentclient', '$propertydescription', '$transactiontype', '$applicabledocument', '$received', '$paid')") or die(mysql_error()); 
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
echo "Succesfully added transaction. Updating table...";
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"48\">";
mysql_close($con);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: read about "a" tag in html.

Comment: add your code here ....

Comment: If your chart is generated by some third party plugin/ library then search study manual for hyperlink labels for that library.

Comment: It is all made by me, Ill show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your uploads are stored in the client doc folder and you have run the query to get the recordset from the transactions table...

```
<a href="/clientdoc/<?php echo $applicabledocument; ?>" title="example title">link text</a>
```

Another point, looking at the code, sending raw $_POST values direct to the db is asking for sql injection trouble. Have a look at either htmlentities with ENT_QUOTES set or the input filters available with php.